# Google UIAutocompleteResultController for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to add pre-defined text on in the result controller, is there any way that it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete` with

> google-maps-sdk-ios

https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete

[image]

Comment: Any swift library for this?

Comment: use this for swift project 
https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete